# Need help in logic and statements

Tags: logic

I am stuck with some questions. Please help me out. Thanks.

> If $P(x):x^2 < 12$, then $P(1.5)$ is a statement  (I think yes. As the Universe of $x$ is not given but can be taken as set of Real Numbers.)
>
> If $Q(n): n+3=6$, then  $Q(m)$ is the statement   (I think no. As $m$ is a variable and we can not have variables or undetermined values in a statement.)
>
> If $P(y): 1+2+3+\ldots+y =0$, then $P(5)$ is the statement    (I think yes.)
>
> If $Q(m):m \leq 3^m$, then $Q(k)$ is the statement.   (I think no. As $m$ is a variable and we can not have variables or undetermined values in a statement.)
>
> Where **Statement** is a sentence that evaluates to either true or false but not both.

Comment: By "statement", do you mean a well-formed formula with no free variables? (sometimes called a "sentence").

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Yes. A statement according the book(Discrete Structures by Kolman,Busby & Ross) is a sentence which satisfies p->q

Comment: I don't understand what it means to say that a sentence "satisfies p->q"... Do you mean, "it is a sentence [well-formed formula with no free variables] that is of the form $P\rightarrow Q$ for some $P$ and some $Q$"?

Comment: Are you sure? In the third edition they define a statement to be a declarative sentence that is either true or false but not both.

Comment: @Arturo: Akito almost certainly won’t know the terms *well-formed formula* and *free variable*, and unless the sixth edition of KB&R is astonishingly different from the third, the technical meaning of *sentence* in logic will also be unfamiliar.

Comment: If Brian's definition is the correct one, then your thinking seems to be correct in all four items.

Comment: Note to @all: I think the [logic] tag does not fit this question, but I cannot think of an appropriate tag.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, you are right. I am misinterpreted it by mistake.

Comment: @Srivatsan: It’s from a sophomore-level discrete math course, if that helps.

Comment: Then I agree with Arturo: you’ve answered all four of them correctly and given appropriate reasons.

Answer (score 1):

*A CW post to eliminate this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

As has been remarked in the comments, your suggested answers and accompanying reasoning, which yield the answers:

> Yes, No, Yes, No

are all correct. Cheers!